# Unable to understand Flutter Isolate workaround for "'Window_sendPlatformMessage' (4 arguments) cannot be found" error

Tags: plugins, flutter, dart, dart-isolates

I'm converting a very simplistic label printing app to `Flutter` from Swift. A major component of this app is locally cached databases for offline access of products.

While I could download and cache all of the 12,000+ products on the main thread, this is a terrible, terrible solution for such a heavy operation, and I'd really like to avoid that except as a last resort. Even as a last resort, I'd have much more trouble convincing my employer to let me migrate from Swift to Flutter if background threading is not possible for a basic task such as caching online data to a local database.

As a result, I've been exploring Isolates. In the process, I ran into the error `"'Window_sendPlatformMessage' (4 arguments) cannot be found"` whenever I try to cache data using [sqflite](https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite) and [path_provider](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider) while on an `Isolate`.

Now I'm reading on [github](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/26413) and [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54127158/flutter-window-sendplatformmessage-4-arguments-cannot-be-found) that Isolates don't support the use of plugins (possibly packages?) except in a wonky workaround kind of way. I've tried a [plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_isolate) that just crashes my app with a very cryptic stack trace when I try to use it, so it looks like a workaround is the only way.

I've just started building with flutter about a week ago and just started on Isolates about two days ago, so my basic understanding of everything is currently shallow. On the flutter repo, there is a [comment](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/13937#issuecomment-357197834) that seems to outline a workaround for the plugin issue, which I hope will allow me to use `path_provider` and `sqflite` to cache the data I'm getting from my web API.

Could a more experienced Flutter developer break down this explanation into baby-bites for me?

## *edit:*

As noted in an answer below, `sqflite` is already async, and apparently runs on a different thread than the main one, so it looks like my specific situation will be solved by using compute for my dart-pure API call to get JSON data and using regular `sqflite` for storage. The need for a beginner's guide to wonky Isolate workarounds remains nonetheless, so I'm leaving the question open.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Attempt at explanation**

I, too, find the wording of the workaround post in that thread very confusing and I can't really make full sense of it either, however what the poster seems to be suggesting is that you use `setMockMessageHandler` to intercept data from `invokeMethod`.

`setMockMessageHandler` overrides the handler function which would otherwise take the encoded data and pass it on to the native side, allowing you to use your own function. So when you set a mock message handler for a channel you can "hijack" the data and pass it through a `SendPort` back to your main isolate.

Once you have the message on the main isolate you can then use `BinaryMessenger.send` to send the data to its intended destination. This is the step that breaks if you're in an isolate other than the main one, so now you have bypassed that problem.

Once you receive your data back to the main thread you pass it on back to the isolate and decode it there using a custom message handler that you create with `BinaryMessages.setMessageHandler`.

**Workaround package**

If you still need it, I made a package ([Isolate Handler](https://pub.dev/packages/isolate_handler#-analysis-tab-)) using a workaround very similar to the one you are asking about.

The downside of course of any workaround relying on `setMockMessageHandler` is that you do need to provide it with the channel names that you will be using. You can find these channel names in the source files by you looking for where the `MethodChannel`s are set.

It seems that sqflite uses `com.tekartik.sqflite` and path_provider uses `plugins.flutter.io/path_provider`, so in order to use them in an isolate with Isolate Handler you would do the following:

```
IsolateHandler().spawn(
    entryPoint,
    channels: [
      MethodChannel('com.tekartik.sqflite'),
      MethodChannel('plugins.flutter.io/path_provider'),
    ]
);

void entryPoint(HandledIsolateContext context) {
  final messenger = HandledIsolate.initialize(context);
  // <Your previous isolate entry point here>
}
```

---

## Update 2019-09-04:

I ended up solving this problem for myself by starting an isolate from the native side instead. I took inspiration from the official Flutter plugin [android_alarm_manager](https://pub.dev/packages/android_alarm_manager#-readme-tab-). While that plugin is specific to Android and that was enough for my specific project, it is possible to do it in iOS as well as shown in the now-archived [location_background_plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/location_background_plugin#-readme-tab-) as well as the Medium post referenced below.

A very comprehensive (if a bit overly focused on Geofencing) post by one of the Flutter developers on the process of initiating isolates from the native side is [available on Medium](https://medium.com/flutter/executing-dart-in-the-background-with-flutter-plugins-and-geofencing-2b3e40a1a124).

**Summary of steps taken in the post**:

1. ([GitHub](https://gist.github.com/bkonyi/3dcbb962308582d6f7e8446c3f1c6994#file-geofencepluginpt2-dart)) Set up a plugin referencing the callback dispatcher on the Dart side using `PluginUtilities.getCallbackHandle`
2. ([GitHub](https://gist.github.com/bkonyi/b49b4d687f8e8b0a7c6744bb01ca5924#file-geofencecallbackdispatcher-dart)) Create the callback dispatcher itself, which:

   - Initializes the MethodChannel(s) you want to access.
   - Calls `WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized()` to set up internal state needed for `MethodChannel`.
   - Calls `setMethodCallHandler` on the MethodChannel(s) to listen for background events from the native side of your plugin and invokes your callback when events trigger it.
   - Finally alerts the native side plugin that the callback handler is ready for events using `invokeMethod`.
3. Implement native code to perform background execution.

   - ([GitHub](https://github.com/bkonyi/FlutterGeofencing/tree/master/android/src/main/kotlin/io/flutter/plugins/geofencing)) Android
   - ([GitHub](https://github.com/bkonyi/FlutterGeofencing/tree/master/ios/Classes)) iOS
4. Set permissions to allow background execution as a service.

   - Android

     - ([GitHub](https://gist.github.com/bkonyi/7a5a7aaeb813012f9092d87d4a237189#file-androidmanifest1-xml)) Register plugin objects with AndroidManifest.xml as service.
     - ([GitHub](https://gist.github.com/bkonyi/b632b4437400c82d46b1205988dd5b9a#file-application-java)) Create a custom `FlutterActivity`.
     - ([GitHub](https://gist.github.com/bkonyi/d109c99e704a4173761ff9f93f4e5fc4#file-application-xml)) Update `application` field in `AndroidManifest.xml`, set it to the newly created `FlutterActivity`.
   - iOS

     - ([GitHub](https://gist.github.com/bkonyi/e599befe2507ccbc4feac2deec848991#file-info1-plist)). Modify `Info.plist` to request permissions
     - ([GitHub](https://gist.github.com/bkonyi/856e6c29c3abb359cd1414396a5f2cda#file-appdelegate-m)) Set a reference to the application’s plugin registrant from the application's `AppDelegate`.
5. ([GitHub](https://gist.github.com/bkonyi/7710ceffb0ca01a01875babc2bec556e#file-garageremoteinit-dart)) Initialize plugin on Dart side when the application starts (e.g. from `main`.)

**Conclusion**

This is by no means a simple solution and I still hope there will be a better one provided by the Flutter team, but it's a working one at least with no hickups or unexpected behavior.

I would consider this the only solution ready for production at the moment.

Comment: Interesting. However sqflite is not cross isolate safe regarding transactions so you might get corrupted data if there are concurrent writes so I'm not sure that it is a safe solution (currently).

Comment: This looks promising! I may not be able to test it for a few weeks, so I upvoted, but am not marking as the answer yet. As soon as I have a chance to test, I will let you know how this worked for me.

Comment: @A.L.Strine I ended up finding a better solution for my own project eventually by instead starting the isolate from the native side. I will update my post.

Answer (score 1):

I won't respond exactly to your question (how to use isolate) but I would recommend not to use isolate at this point. sqflite runs in a background thread. Yes, preparing data will be in the main thread so you should definitely never save 12000 items at a time, but downloading/saving items by 50, (or 100 or 1000 depending on the size of each item - to experiment) in a transaction (even better batch) should be fine.

For intensive computing on lots of item (could include json decoding of downloaded data or preparing the maps to save for sqflite), you can use the `compute` flutter method.

It might involve some smart coding on your side if you need to display the full list (paging if needed) but I think nothing should prevent you from doing what you need 'in the background', i.e. without blocking the UI.

Comment: I will try this in the morning, the compute method is looking very promising - I was going to build something similar to what it seems to do, I'm excited to see if it works.

Comment: The compute method, although very useful, does NOT use the workaround necessary to resolve the "'Window_sendPlatformMessage' (4 arguments) cannot be found" error. I'm still unable to use packages/plugins of even the simplest kind.

Compute did reduce a lot of code and cleaned things up significantly, however.

Comment: As you experimented, you should use compute only for intensive algorithm (I'm still not sure what kind of data is supported for input and output, I only tested with simple types), not for calling plugins or external packages methods if you don't know what they are doing.

Comment: I see now that you said sqflite runs on a background thread - do you happen to know if that mean it uses two sets of native code to multi-thread, or an isolate in dart? I skimmed the readme and the use guide and didn't find a section on async implementation, so I'm guessing you found that out by looking at the code itself?

Comment: I was assuming that the async implementation was through futures

Comment: It uses a native thread on the native side (iOS and Android).